# How can a create a "progressive jpg" image using cloudinary and nodejs?

Tags: node.js, cloudinary

I need to create a image, which is resized + watermaked + should be progressive jpg image.

```js
function getProcessImageFromCloudinary(imgUrl, name, format,wid,hei,cb){
 cloudinary.uploader.upload(imgUrl, function(result) {
  cb(result);
 },
 {
   public_id: name, width:wid, height:hei,format:format,crop:'fit',transformation:{overlay:'watermark', gravity:'south_east',x:5,y:5}
 });

}
```

Have successfully watermarked and resized, need help with the progressive tag, how can I add this in the same transformation?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: The question is clearly mentioned, that how can I create a progressive image, I have successfully resized and added watermarked. Needed help on progressive tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the `flags` parameter to `progressive`. For more information:
http://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_transformations#flags_parameter

Comment: Thanks for answering, had got the answer, forgot to update it here.